# do while loop not looping properly

Tags: c++

Practicing on a battle game, keeping it basic for now, I am trying to allow the user to continue entering 'A' to attack, and I want the loop to let the user continue attacking until the monsters health is 0 or below 0. The problem is that it attacks once, it reduces the hitpoints and displays its remained hitpoints however, its not allowing the user to attack again. This is the piece I am currently stuck on.

```
    if (level ==1 )

    {
        do
        {
            cout<<"\n\n";
            cout<<"Level "<<level<<" Defeat the guard\n\n";
            cout<<"Guard Stats\n";
            cout<<"Power: "<<monster.displaystrength()<<endl;
            cout<<"Defense: "<<monster.displaydefense()<<endl;
            cout<<"Health: "<<monster.displayhealth()<<"\n\n"<<endl;

            cout<<"Enter A) Attack\n";
            cout<<"Enter D) Defend\n";
            cout<<"Enter S) Special\n";
            cout<<"Enter N) Do Nothing\n\n";
            cin>>battleChoice;


            if(battleChoice =='A' || battleChoice == 'a')
            {
                srand(time(NULL));
                dps = rand()%10+1;
                cout<<"Damage done: " << dps << endl;
                monsterHealth = monster.displayhealth();
                totalMonsterHealth = monsterHealth - dps;
                cout<<"Monster health remaining: "<<totalMonsterHealth<<"\n\n"<<endl;

                return totalMonsterHealth;
            }

        }while (totalMonsterHealth!=0);

            if(battleChoice == 'D' || battleChoice == 'd')
            {
                cout<<"Defending\n"; //prototype
            }

            if(battleChoice == 'S' || battleChoice == 's')
            {
                cout<<"Using special attack\n"; //prototype
            }
            if(battleChoice == 'N' || battleChoice == 'n')
            {
                cout<<"Do nothing, Loop again.\n"; //prototype
            }

    }
```

Comment: `return` returns from the function.

Comment: I'm guessing it runs right up to the line `return totalMonsterHealth`? ;-) That line terminates the function, and therefore also the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning `totalMonsterHealth` in

```
if(battleChoice =='A' || battleChoice == 'a')
```

So when the user hits `A` or `a` it will exit the loop

Comment: Makes sense. Let me see what else i can try.

Comment: And maybe you want to put all those `if-statements` inside the `do-while loop`, cause I think you need to check everytime what the user want to do.